# APK files start with the same bytes as Doc files

Tags: python, io, byte, file-type

I have a malware analysis engine that I've been working on for months, I'm starting to implement APK and doc files (docm, docx, pdf, etc). One of the ways I check if a file is a doc file is by running it through an analyzer that reads the first 2-4 bytes and checks what they are. If they are what match a doc or PDF file I return true. Recently I've been looking at APK files and noticed that when I read the first few bytes (up to 10 from what I've noticed) the APK bytes match that of doc bytes. For example, here is my test list:

```
print(is_doc("H:\\tests\\malware\\doc\\ds7002.pdf"))
print(is_doc("H:\\tests\\malware\\doc\\doc1.docm.doc"))
print(is_doc("H:\\tests\\malware\\doc\\stuff1.docx"))
print(is_doc("H:\\test\\malware\\doc\\GreyEnergyDropper.doc"))
print(is_doc("samples\\wildfire-test-elf-file"))
print(is_doc("samples\\binary.bin"))
print(is_doc("samples\\RR.apk"))
print(is_doc("h:\\tests\\apks\\Official Trump 2020 App_v2.3.0_apkpure.com.apk"))
```

And here is the code I use to tell them apart:

```
def is_doc(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        if f.read(4) in [b"%PDF"]:
            return True
        if f.read(2) in [b"\xD0\xCF", b"PK", "\x14\x00"]:
            return True
        return False
```

Now this works really well and I really like it, however the last two files should fail. But they didn't so I went ahead and checked the first 10 bytes in the files:

```
first 10 of ds7002.pdf: ('%PDF-1.6\r%')
first 10 of doc1.docm.doc: ('PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00')
first 10 of stuff1.docx: ('PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00')
first 10 of GreyEnergyDropper.doc: ('PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00')
first 10 of wildfire-test-elf-file: ('\x7fELF\x02\x01\x01\x00\x00\xfd')
first 10 of binary.bin: ('MZ\x90\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00')
first 10 of RR.apk: ('PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
first 10 of Official Trump 2020 App_v2.3.0_apkpure.com.apk: ('PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00')
```

As you can see the doc files are matching the APK files which is causing some issues for me in the long run. How can I successfully check if a file is a APK if the first 10 bytes are the same for doc files as well?

Answer (score 0):

Right after posting this I saw that there's a difference in the bytes:

APK: `PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`

Doc: `PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00`

It'll take some work but I think I can just read the first 7 bytes and successfully determine the differences